# Action of the Euclidean group, generalizing linearity?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and two elements $(A,a)$ and $(B,b)$ of the Euclidean group $E(2)$. If the relation
$$[(A,a)(B,b)](v) = v$$
holds, can I say that $(A,a)(B,b)$ is the neutral element of $E(2)$?

If the elements of the Euclidean group acted as linear transformations, it would be true, but they don't: $(A,a)(v + w) = (A,a)(v) + (A,0)(w) \neq (A,a)(v) + (A,a)(w)$.

Comment: What does the notation $(A,a)$ mean?

Comment: Who says that this would be true for linear transformations?

Comment: @LeeMosher best guess: $(A,a)(v) = Av + a$

Comment: @Marc also, does the "neutral element" mean $(I,0)$?

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a standard notation. Omnomnomnom guessed right both times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This isn't even true for linear transformations; take $A$ to be any nontrivial rotation about the origin, $B=I$, and $v=0$. Then $ABv=v$ but $AB\neq I$.

Comment: Hmm... what about if we exclude the zero vector? I will get back on this later!

Comment: For Euclidean motions, that won't fix the issue. The key idea is that all Euclidean motions, except for pure translations, have fixed points.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. It is true for linear transformations if we exclude the zero vector because then $(A-I)v = 0$ implies $A=I$. But for Euclidean motions, I always find a non-zero vector which is unchanged.